# Sharing calendars between Windows Live accounts

Tags: calendar, office-365

My spouse and I have Windows Live accounts (for our Windows Phone 8's, but let's just focus on the Windows Live end for now) and would like to share our calendars with each other. We haven't been able to do this successfully.

I click on the interface's "Share" button. Then I go to "share with people you choose." I add my spouse and allow "view details" permission. Then I click "Share". I know this has registered because when I get out of the sharing interface and go back in, my spouse's account is listed as having permissions. I've also tried this from my spouse's Windows Live calendar to mine.

The problem is, neither of us have seen any indication that we've received these permissions from the sharing user nor have any way to access each other's calendar. We haven't gotten any emails on either our @outlook email addresses or the emails we used to make the Windows Live account (gmail).

The only specific instructions I have found seem to pertain to Hotmail accounts (I'm still not clear how separate these are) at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/calendar-share-calendar-with-contacts. The steps here show slightly different options than what is available to me. Please help!